# Can't create moor_database.g.dart file

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor, build-runner

every time i run the "build_runner watch" command i get an error that 0/3 actions completed i have all the dependencies with their last update i tried to search the problem but couldn't find any solution yet.. still searching and i hope if i can find some help here:

---

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 395ms

[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 13.4s

[INFO] Setting up file watchers...
[INFO] Setting up file watchers completed, took 12ms

[INFO] Waiting for all file watchers to be ready...
[INFO] Waiting for all file watchers to be ready completed, took 108ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.3s

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 2ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] 1.1s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[INFO] 2.1s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[INFO] 5.2s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[INFO] 6.3s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[INFO] 11.1s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[INFO] 12.3s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/db/db.dart:
Error running MoorGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/db/db.dart:
Error running DaoGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[INFO] Running build completed, took 12.6s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 95ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 12.7s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running this command, *flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs*

Comment: and it seems that you have got errors in your moor code where you are implementing 'TypeConverters'

Answer (score 2):

did you try deleting moor_database.g.dart and then running "build_runner watch" again?

Comment: i just had to run it all over again from the start i am still learning so i just made a new project did everything again worked perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

please look over .g.dart file name should me exactly like database file name, i.e. id ur file name is 'database_helper.dart' then it should be part 'database_helper.g.dart' then only g.dart file will get created

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).