# flutter: Can't create moor_database.g.dart file

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I am trying to learn [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter) so i added some dependencies into pupspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  moor_flutter: ^2.1.1
  provider: ^4.0.4
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  path: ^1.6.4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  moor_generator: ^2.4.0
  build_runner: ^1.8.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

After installing these dependencies I create a table class inside `lib -> data -> moor_database.dart` file:

```
import 'package:moor_flutter/moor_flutter.dart';
part 'moor_database.g.dart';

class Tasks extends Table {
  IntColumn get id =>
      integer().autoIncrement().call();
  TextColumn get name => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 50)();
  DateTimeColumn get dueDate => dateTime().nullable()();
  BoolColumn get completed => boolean().withDefault(Constant(false))();
}

@UseMoor(tables: [Tasks])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase()
      : super(FlutterQueryExecutor.inDatabaseFolder(
            path: 'db.sqlite', logStatements: true));

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}
```

I want to generate dart code by :

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

But i got this error:

```
$ flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 349ms

[INFO] Setting up file watchers...
[INFO] Setting up file watchers completed, took 12ms

[INFO] Waiting for all file watchers to be ready...
[INFO] Waiting for all file watchers to be ready completed, took 165ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 68ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 889ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] 1.6s elapsed, 0/1 actions completed.
[INFO] 3.4s elapsed, 0/1 actions completed.
[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/data/moor_database.dart:
Error running MoorGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/data/moor_database.dart:
Error running DaoGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[INFO] Running build completed, took 3.7s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 50ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 3.7s
```

After googleing i found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491042/cant-create-moor-database-g-dart-file) :
but after running `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` i got this error:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 350ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 79ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 896ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 11ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 47ms

[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/data/moor_database.dart (cached):
Error running MoorGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[SEVERE] moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/data/moor_database.dart (cached):
Error running DaoGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'typeConverter' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: typeConverter
[SEVERE] Failed after 71ms
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked a question in it's official repo git and i got this answer :

> It works if you replace this with integer().autoIncrement()(). The generator should emit a more helpful error message though, I'll take a look at why that didn't happen here.

I chnaged:

```
IntColumn get id =>integer().autoIncrement().call();
```

to :

```
IntColumn get id =>integer().autoIncrement()();
```

my problem gone.

Comment: This also solves `Bad state: No element` error.